# label input type radio

Tags: html, css

I am trying to css the input type radio button, and it does not work. The problem is that the input tag is inside the label tag and I am not able to change it.

```css
input{
  display:none;
}


label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);

}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<label for="female"><input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an inner substitute for your input because the + only selects the next element on the same level.

```css
input{
  display:none;
}


span:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);

}
input[type=radio]:checked + span:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<label for="female">
  <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
  <span for="female"></span>
  Female
</label
```

Comment: Is there anyway to change the css to work with the current html code? As i am not able add the span tag. :/

Comment: Ok. I used Jquery to append a span tag. Now it is working. Many thanks

Comment: Hi! If there is <a> tag between the input and span, it is not going to work. Do you have any suggestion for this case?

Comment: You have to add a to the pointer + only takes the next following element (input[type=radio]:checked + a + span:before)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.control{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
input{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
input:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

input[type=radio]:checked:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<input id="female" class="control" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
<label for="female" class="control">
Female</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to put your label after `input:radio`

```
<input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
<label for="female"> Female.</label>
```

Comment: Thanks.I am not able to put label after input:radio, but the problem was solved. :)